# Checking a value if in array

Tags: php, arrays

How do i correct my code ..i would like to check a value if is in array

```
$years[] = ''.$myyear.'';
$years_array = "array('" . implode( "','", $years) . "');";

if (in_array("2017", $years_array)) 

{
//do this
}

else

{
//do this
}
```

Comment: `$years_array` is a string

Comment: The code seems to be right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `in_array` with `if` clause looks fine, but `year_array` is wrong (which is string not array)

You can define `year_array` simply like below

```
$years_array = array(2015,2016,2017,2018);
```

OR

```
// Define array
$years_array = array();

// Add elements to array
$years_array[]  = 2015;
$years_array[]  = 2016;
$years_array[] = 2017;
```

In case if you have list of years as string separated by comma, then you can create array using <kbd>[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)</kbd> function like below

```
// this is string
$year_string = '2015,2016,2017,2018';

// this is array
$year_array  = explode(',', $year_string);

// print string 
print $year_string.PHP_EOL;

// print the contents of array
print_r($year_array);
```

meanwhile you can read more about `arrays` from <kbd>[here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you but is it possible to do it automatically without manually defining  the years ?

Comment: @blackrx: automatically meaning from string ? please see my update

Comment: extract from $myyear

Comment: @blackrx : see update may be thats what you wanted, from string to array where separator being comma

Comment: Thank you very much  @Ashkay Hegde. Solved. Have a nice day

Comment: @blackrx glad to know, I wish you the same